# Where & how to find out what can be automized on SFDX scratch org creation

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

How do I find out what can be automized regarding scratch org settings and preferences? And where?

I just learned that things that cannot be directly set in `project-scratch-def.json` might be pushed as metadata to the scratch org.

On my list of things I would like to auto-set is:

1. Enable Out-of-Office
2. Enable Manager Groups
3. Set access to reports in the package
4. Allow org admin to Login as other users
5. Set Lightning default home page

*Note: I work on a managed packaged.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Winter '19 documentation [Scratch Org Definition Configuration Values](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.216.0.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm) includes a "Scratch Org Settings" section that says:

> In Winter ’19 and later, scratch org settings are the format for
>   defining org preferences in the scratch org definition. Because you
>   can use all Metadata API settings, they are the most comprehensive way
>   to configure a scratch org. If a setting is supported in Metadata API,
>   it’s supported in scratch orgs. Settings provide you with fine-grained
>   control because you can define values for all fields for a setting,
>   rather than just enabling or disabling it.

and:

> Although the Settings are upper camel case in the Metadata API
>   Developer Guide, be sure to indicate them as lower camel case in the
>   scratch org definition.

So that sounds like the `settings` property is an answer with the caveat of "If a setting is supported in Metadata API".